# How do I allow the user to only use a number once C#

Tags: c#

Hello I am creating a Magic Square game and I have created a 2D Array to store zeros and create a 3 x 3 board that looks like this...

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

I then created a for loop that asked the user for a integer at [0,0] to [2,2] where it ended so it looked like this assuming it was typed 1-9..

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

My question is how do I only let the user type a number from 1-9 and only be able to use the number once??

What I have tried:

Tried using bool array but I don't know how to set up

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Too broad. But, options you might consider include just scanning the 9-element array each time a new number is presented, to verify it's not present, or using a `HashSet<int>` to track all the numbers used so far. You should try _something_ before you ask Stack Overflow to do your work for you.

Comment: Use a `HashTable` and every time user gives you a number, check if the hash table has that number. Search for C# hashtable example online.

Comment: Console App or WinForms or Asp.net? If Console, you can restrict what user enters, but can validate it upon entry. For not allowing to enter twice, you can store in `HashSet<int>` check `.Contains` method before accepting the user input.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple just use a list of previously selected numbers

```
var previousNumbers = new List<int>(); // Create list of previous numbers entered
int number;

Console.WriteLine($"Enter new number from 1 to 9 or 0 to exit.");

var valueEntered = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

// try converting key press to an int and check its not 0
while (int.TryParse(valueEntered.ToString(), out number) && number != 0)
{
   if (previousNumbers.Contains(number))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(" has already been entered, try again.");
   }
   else
   {
      // add you number to the list 
      previousNumbers.Add(number); 
      Console.WriteLine(" is a valid number and hasn't been used.");
   }
   // get next value and do the hokey pokey 
   valueEntered = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; 
}
```

Due to popular demand here is another way

```
var previousNumbers = new HashSet<int>(); // Create list of previous numbers entered
int number;

Console.WriteLine($"Enter new number from 1 to 9 or 0 to exit.");

// try converting it to in, and check its not 0
while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) && number >= 1 && number <= 9)
{
   if (!previousNumbers.Add(number))
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"{number} has already been entered, try again.");
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"{number} is a valid number and hasn't been used.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Getting number through each keystroke: This is a rather bizarre way of getting numbers from the user.

Comment: Consider using `HashSet` rather than `List`. Then you don't need to call `Contains` - you can just check the return value of `Add`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Agreed, no points for style and flair, but the point of the exercise was the storing of the numbers.

Comment: @mjwills i like your style

Comment: @CodingYoshi updated for you, im sure this code is worthy of a hat now!

Comment: If you need to something at least once and possibly more times, use the `do while` loop. In your 2nd example you are only asking the user for entry once but I am sure you know that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the number and make a list.

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();

public boolean AddNums(int num){
    if(1<=num&&num<=9&&!nums.Contains(num)){
        nums.Add(num);
        return true;        
    }
    return false;
}
```